# Create new columns in a dataframe with combination of three columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, tabular

I have something like this:

```
       Date  Id  Product  Sales
0  1/1/2001   1       21      1200
1  1/1/2001   1       22      1000
2  1/1/2001   1       23      1500
3  2/1/2001   1       21      300
4  2/1/2001   2       22      200
5  3/1/2001   3       21      400
6  4/1/2001   3       22      500
```

I want to create something like this with same table:

[image]

Comment: Why does 2/1/2001 have 1_22 = 200 in your expected output, when that row is 2_22 in your provided data?

Comment: Please don't link to images of text that could be included using markdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would concatenate ID and Product, and then pivot the result.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame([['1/1/2001',1,21,1200],['1/1/2001',1,22,1000],['1/1/2001',1,23,1500],['2/1/2001',1,21,300],['2/1/2001',2,22,200],['3/1/2001',3,21,400],['4/1/2001',3,22,500]],columns=('Date','Id','Product','Sales'))

df['Id_Prod'] = df['Id'].astype(str).str.cat(df['Product'].astype(str), sep='_')

df.pivot(index='Date',columns='Id_Prod',values='Sales')
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. it did exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I have a date column data type as object and I want to convert it to datetime data type. when I am trying to parse date while loading or trying doing this after loading using --pandas.to_datetime-- its taking too long to convert it since rows are in 100s of millions. Could someone help changing date from object to date type more efficiently and faster.

Comment: you could post that as another question :)

Answer (score 0):

It's way easy to do this via Pivot function of Pandas.

So this is your Dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([['1/1/2001',1,21,1200],['1/1/2001',1,22,1000],['1/1/2001',1,23,1500],['2/1/2001',1,21,300],['2/1/2001',2,22,200],['3/1/2001',3,21,400],['4/1/2001',3,22,500]],columns=('Date','Id','Product','Sales'))
```

Output:

```
    Date    Id  Product Sales
0   1/1/2001    1   21  1200
1   1/1/2001    1   22  1000
2   1/1/2001    1   23  1500
3   2/1/2001    1   21  300
4   2/1/2001    2   22  200
5   3/1/2001    3   21  400
6   4/1/2001    3   22  500
```

Now just use this code:

```
df.pivot(index='Date',columns='Product',values='Sales')
```

And you'll get:

```
Product      21     22      23
Date            
1/1/2001    1200.0  1000.0  1500.0
2/1/2001    300.0   200.0   NaN
3/1/2001    400.0   NaN     NaN
4/1/2001    NaN     500.0   NaN
```

And about the names of the columns, well, you can change it your way or maybe the way they look in my answer, I guess they are alright.

Comment: Exact same answer as mine

Comment: Well, I was writing at the time you posted it. I can remove mine if you want.